How to declare self-referencing foreign key with Drizzle ORM
In a Typescript project, declaring a table using Drizzle on postgres-node as follows:

const contractsTable = pgTable("contracts", {
    id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
    underlyingId: integer("underlying_id").references(() => contractsTable.id),
    //...
})


results in the following Typescript error:
'contractsTable' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
Maintaining a separate type would be impractical because the schema is massive and is subject to change.
Is there a way to get Typescript to infer the correct type? I failed to do this through aliasing or casting the PgIntegerBuilderInitial type.
We also define a relationship as follows:
const contractsRelations = relations(
    contractsTable,
    ({ one, many }) => ({
        underlying: one(contractsTable, {
            fields: [contractsTable.underlyingId],
            references: [contractsTable.id],
        }),
        //...
    })
);

but I do need the database level constraint. Any ideas?

See Drizzle ORM issue: Self reference foreign key break relational query types
#1607

i think you just need to define the column types?
so underlyingId: integer("underlying_id").references((): PgColumn => contractsTable.id),

According to the [BUG]: Self reference foreign key break relational query types #1607, you can solved like this:
export const contractsTable = pgTable("contracts", {
    id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
    underlyingId: integer("underlying_id").references((): AnyPgColumn => contractsTable.id),
})

export const contractsRelations = relations(
    contractsTable,
    ({ one, many }) => ({
        underlying: one(contractsTable, {
            fields: [contractsTable.underlyingId],
            references: [contractsTable.id],
        }),
    })
);


You can create a self reference in the table being created by doing
export const contractsTable = pgTable(
  "contracts",
  {
    id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
    underlyingId: integer("underlying_id"),
  },
  (table) => {
    return {
      parentReference: foreignKey({
        columns: [table.underlyingId],
        foreignColumns: [table.id],
        name: "contracts_underlying_id_fkey",
      }),
    };
  }
);

Correctly generated the foreign key.
Taken from Discord conversations and tested on
   drizzle-kit 0.21.4
   drizzle-orm 0.30.10


This is the one, this is the one you want!
